# Rotation flipping when moving around the sides of objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a game in Unity where a person can pick a surface and walk along all of its sides. I've gotten the movement working, but when I rotate my character around certain angles of corner the character flips 180 degrees in some direction (it's different depending on the corner) and when I want them to move forward the game freaks out as they keep going across the corner over and over again, turning, and going forward across the border again. I'd strongly prefer to keep my character from doing these 180-degree spins and I think it's just due to a flaw in the formula I use to calculate the angle they stand at (which is based around making sure their transform.up is aligned with the point they are meant to stand on). Any ideas on how I fix this rotation formula in Update?

Current formula:

```
     angle = Vector3.Angle(closestPoint, transform.position);
     var t = transform;
     var angles = t.eulerAngles;
     t.LookAt(GravityWellPoint.transform.position);
     t.RotateAround(transform.position, -transform.right, 90);
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, t.rotation, Time.deltaTime * 5.0f);
```

Comment: I can't say I understand your formula. `t` is assigned to `transform`, yet sometimes you sometimes refer to both. The last line seems to set the transform's rotation to some interpolation between its own rotation and.. its own rotation. And `angle` and `angles` are assigned but not used. I can't offer a solution, my only advice is: stay clear of euler angles. They are often the cause of problems like yours. Try to do this purely in quaternions if you can.

Comment: One more thing, since it seems you are trying to do time independent damping using lerp, [you should read this](https://www.rorydriscoll.com/2016/03/07/frame-rate-independent-damping-using-lerp/)

Comment: Sorry but if you want help you should try again that formula, its explained above why it doesn't make sense, it would help if you go through the logic again and edit the question to fix those inaccuracies. You could also use some break lines to format the text nicely into sections making easy to read your thought process.

Answer (score 0):

Got this solution from a different forum and it worked:

So this is actually not a trivial problem to solve. If you try doing it by calculating angles etc. you almost always end up with a similar spinning/flipping issue in certain positions. You can solve it by doing the math, but it's a pain. I usually like to use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to solve this kind of problem. you can feed in the desired forward and upward directions. So you can calculate the desired upward direction like so:

```cs
Vector3 targetUpDirection = transform.position - GravityWellPoint.transform.position;
```

Then you would do the following:

```cs
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward,targetUpDirection);
```

but this doesn't quite work. `LookRotation` will ensure that your forward direction is exactly the one you specify, and then chooses the upward direction that's the closest possible to the one you specify. So you will find that we don't actually manage to point our object upward in the way we intended. However, there is an unintuitive solution we can apply instead.

Calculate the upward direction in the same way, then use `LookRotation` to rotate our object to point its forward face in exactly our desired upwards direction, and its upward face towards the current forward direction:

```cs
Vector3 targetUpDirection = transform.position - GravityWellPoint.transform.position;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetUpDirection, transform.forward);
```

Now our object is aligned perfectly but is the wrong way up. We can use `LookRotation` again, to swap the upwards and forward directions:

```cs
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.up, transform.forward);
```

For clarity/TLDR here is the complete code for my solution:

```cs
//find the desired up direction:
Vector3 targetUpDirection = transform.position - other.position;
//face forward/upward via black magic
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetUpDirection, transform.forward);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.up, transform.forward);
```